# Partitioning a sparse matrix into sparse sub-matrices

Tags: tensors, sparse-arrays, partitions

Given a normal matrix, for example

```
m = Array[a,{4,4}]
```

which has dimensions `{4,4}`, I can partition it by using:

```
m2 = Partition[m,{2,2}],
```

which has dimensions `{2,2,2,2}`.

Now, if `m` is a sparse array, for example:

```
m = SparseArray[Table[{i,i}->i,{i,1,4}],{4,4}]
```

I would like to be able to partition it in a similar manner but with the result being a sparse matrix. The command `Partition` always yields a dense matrix.
Of course, I could do something like:

```
SparseArray[ArrayRules[Partition[m,{2,2}]]]
```

but it would be inefficient since it creates a dense matrix inbetween.

Comment: I'm not sure how to accomplish what you want, but I thought I'd add that for your example m you can do `m=SparseArray[{i_,i_}:>i,{4,4}]`

Comment: Why not use `SparseArray@(Partition[m, {2, 2}])` ?

Comment: @jose Because `SparseArray@Partition[m,{2,2}]` would first apply `Partition[#,{2,2}]&` to the sparse array, converting it to a dense array, and then reconvert it into another sparse array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape):

```
new = ArrayReshape[m, {2,2,2,2}];
new //OutputForm
new //MatrixForm //TeXForm
```

> SparseArray[<4>, {2, 2, 2, 2}]
>
> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 2 \\
>  0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 0 \\
>  3 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

*Addendum*

Note that [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape) and [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition) yield different results:

```
Normal @ ArrayReshape[m, {2,2,2,2}] == Partition[m, {2,2}]
```

> False

If you want to have [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape) return the same matrix as [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition), then you need to post-process with [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose):

```
Equal[
    Normal @ Transpose[ArrayReshape[m, {2,2,2,2}], {1,3,2,4}],
    Partition[m,{2,2}]
]
```

> True